# Why are some iOS assets not showing at retina resolution?

Tags: ios, iphone

In one of my projects, many built-in assets, such as the clear button in UITextField or UISearchBar objects, the UITableViewIndexSearch image, and the activity indicator in the status bar set by UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible don't show at the correct resolution. I've noticed this on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus devices running iOS 8.4, as well as all of the simulators running iOS 8.4. I have other projects that don't show this issue.

Screenshots are here: http://imgur.com/a/7TMlE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced this as well, in my case the cause was various view controllers being created too early in the application life-cycle (in the init method of the app delegate, i.e. before `didFinishLaunching` had been called)  and also before the creation of the initial `UIWindow`.

Moving view controller creation to `didFinishLaunching`, after the window has been created solved it.

Comment: That's it! I was creating my rootViewController at declaration, `var rootViewController = SplashViewController()`. Moving that to `didFinishLaunching` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Those are system elements, so that’s pretty weird. Try deleting and re-adding the simulators in the Xcode Devices window: **Window** → **Devices** or <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>.

Comment: I've tried that with no luck. It also happens on actual devices.

Comment: Are you sure it's iOS 8?

Comment: Yep, I've seen it on multiple iOS 8 devices

Comment: Isn't that a bit heavy-handed? This only seems to affect one of my projects, so I've gotta believe it's something related to specifically one project that causes an issue with iOS. I just was hoping someone else has seen the issue too and found a workaround. I can try reinstalling Xcode at some point, but I don't have time right now, nor faith that it will actually solve the issue.

Comment: Definitely heavy handed, but your problem is super weird. can you post your project, or reproduce it in a trivial sample project?

Comment: I can't post my project, but when I have some time I'll try to reproduce with a test project.

Comment: I have resintalled Xcode, that still hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: Can you try that same project on another machine?

Comment: I've done that as well, no luck. Definitely seems to be with the project.